# How to use Future<bool> in Widget

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a Future function in my Provider Repository. However it is `Future<bool>` since I need `async` for http request.

```
Future<bool> hasCard() async {
    String token = await getToken();
    var body = jsonEncode({"token": token, "userID": user.getUserID()});

    var res = await http.post((baseUrl + "/hasCard"), body: body, headers: {
      "Accept": "application/json",
      "content-type": "application/json"
    });

    print(res.toString());

    if (res.statusCode == 200) {
      this.paymentModel = PaymentModel.fromJson(json.decode(res.body));
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
```

And in my Widget I want to check this value:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var user = Provider.of<UserRepository>(context);
    if(user.hasCard())
    {
      //do something
    }
```

But I get an error message:

> Conditions must have a static type of 'bool'.dart(non_bool_condition)

Since it is a `Widget` type I cannot use `async` here. What could be the way to solve this?

Comment: You should use a futurebuilder, where while waiting for data you can show a progresshud

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `FutureBuilder`, it will build the widget according to the `future` value, which will be null until the `future` is completed. Here is an example.

```
FutureBuilder(
  future: hasCard(),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.data == null)
      return Container(
          width: 20,
          height: 20,
          child: CircularProgressIndicator());
    if (snapshot.hasData) // something has returned
      return Icon(
        Icons.check,
        color: Colors.green,
      );
    else
      return Icon(
        Icons.cancel,
        color: Colors.red,
      );
  },
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well not only for a `Future<bool>` for any other future you can use the `FutureBuilder` where the future is what returns you the type of future and snapshot is the data recieved from it.

```
  FutureBuilder(
      future: hasCard(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.data != null){
          print(snapshot.data)}
        else{
         print("returned data is null!")}  
      },
    )
```

and I would suggest assigning a default value to your bool.

good luck!